# Using .less to get the width of the screen

Tags: less

I want to make a page that has a 200px header and a gradient that stretches from each side of the 200px to the edge of the screen. Can i use .less to say: make the width of each gradient section the width of the screen - 200px, divided by 2 (because there are 2 gradients, one on each side)

Comment: LESS **is** CSS. If you can't do it with CSS, you won't be able to do it with LESS.

Answer (score 2):

LESS compiles to CSS, so it can't measure.
If I understand your question correctly, you could make a gradient 100% percent width, and position it behind your header, and give your header a background color.

HTML:

```
<div id="gradient-wrapper">
  <header>
    [...]
  </header>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
#gradient-wrapper {
  // CSS for gradient
  width: 100%;

  header {
    width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```